# Stored Procedure Parameters - sometimes NULL

Tags: .net, asp.net, vb.net, stored-procedures

i have a stored procedure to update a table. not all fields are required and some can be blank.

for example, title is not required, but when it's blank i get an error

```
          Dim ptitle As New SqlParameter("@title", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 20)
    ptitle.Value = objFormat.CheckSQL(title)
    myCommand.Parameters.Add(ptitle)
```

- ex {"Procedure or Function 'sp_UpdateUser' expects parameter '@title', which was not supplied."} System.Exception

how can i fix it so that it allows for nulls if the data field is blank?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your stored procedure, give the `title` a default value of `NULL` and this should resolve your issue.

```
@title NVARCHAR(20) = NULL
```

Answer (score 1):

The first thing to do is to initialize the value of @Title in sp_UpdateUser as such:

```
alter procedure sp_UpdateUser
@Title varchar(50) = null,

...additional sql code here
```

Secondly, it depends on what value you provide to the `ptitle` through `objFormat.CheckSQL(title)`. If it provides an empty string, then you'll need an additional statement in your stored proc:

```
If @Title = '' set @Title = null
```

Answer (score 0):

in the stored procedure definition, you can write the default value of the parameter, for example

@title nvarchar(20) = NULL,
...
...

in this way the parameter is optional and the sp call will not fail when you do not provide it.

at least we use this approach on SQL 2008 stored procedures.

Answer (score 0):

Convert the input fields to something sane. Null string to "" and Null ints to 0 (if possible)

Answer (score 0):

You can explicitly set your variables to NULL values within the stored procedure.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this inside your stored procedure:

```
@title NVARCHAR(20) = NULL
```

Or use something like this in your vb.net code

```
Sub InsertValues (Optional Title as String = "",...)
```